# Active Directory: How do I specify an objectGUID when I create a new entry?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create entries in AD where I know their objectGUIDs up front. AD replies `WILL_NOT_PERFORM`. Is there an LDAP control or something I can issue that will force it to comply?

Here's the test LDIF for what it's worth:

`dn: cn=Pylon,ou=Visitors/Other Accounts,dc=my,dc=domain
cn: Pylon
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectGUID:: B6GkyNqghEGE1siKxIUxog==`

Note: I am properly encoding the GUID as MS's binary representation (little-endian int, two little-endian shorts, eight bytes). I'm running `ldapadd` remotely, authenticated via GSSAPI and the user is an administrator. If I take away the `objectGUID` it naturally inserts the record.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID is set by the system and cannot be changed nor can it be specified.